# No Plotting all values of X in xaxis and why there is the background grey?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colors, background-color, axis

I would like to get a plot with less data on xaxis. I have this very simple script. I put a 'range' for xaxis. Furthemore I would like that my background was white with contours black and not grey (see figure). How can I do?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
# Increase the plot size and font size.
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (60,30)
plt.xticks(fontsize=40)
plt.yticks(fontsize=40)
plt.grid(True, color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5, axis='y') 
# Plot the learning curve.
plt.plot(df_stats['Training Loss'], color='b', marker='.', linestyle='solid', mec='b', markersize=24, markerfacecolor='white', label="Training", linewidth=7)
plt.plot(df_stats['Valid. Loss'], color='g', marker='.', linestyle='solid',  mec='b', markersize=24, markerfacecolor='white',label="Validation", linewidth=7)
# Label the plot.
plt.title("Training & Validation Loss",fontsize=60)
plt.xlabel("Epoch", fontsize=52)
plt.ylabel("Loss", fontsize=52)
plt.legend(fontsize=50)
plt.xticks(list(range(1, 72)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the second point, please research what `sns.set(style='darkgrid')` does.

Comment: I tried to remove that line, but the background is grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the X-axis ticks to a lower frequency, you will need to change the `xticks` to a lower frequency. One way to do this using `numpy.arange()`.

Regarding the background color, the default is white. But, if for reason it is not, you can set it to white using the plot and axis `facecolor()` to white explicitly.

The code below is the updated version with these changes. Note that I used some dummy data to demonstrate the same.

**Code**

```
df_stats= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Training Loss', 'Valid. Loss'])
df_stats['Training Loss'] = list(range(1,72))
df_stats['Valid. Loss'] = df_stats['Training Loss'] * 2.1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()

# Background color of outer area
plt.figure(facecolor='white')
# Background color of the plot area
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor("white")

# Increase the plot size and font size.
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (60,30)
plt.xticks(fontsize=40)
plt.yticks(fontsize=40)
plt.grid(True, color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5, axis='y') 
# Plot the learning curve.
plt.plot(df_stats['Training Loss'], color='b', marker='.', linestyle='solid', mec='b', markersize=24, markerfacecolor='white', label="Training", linewidth=7)
plt.plot(df_stats['Valid. Loss'], color='g', marker='.', linestyle='solid',  mec='b', markersize=24, markerfacecolor='white',label="Validation", linewidth=7)
# Label the plot.
plt.title("Training & Validation Loss",fontsize=60)
plt.xlabel("Epoch", fontsize=52)
plt.ylabel("Loss", fontsize=52)
plt.legend(fontsize=50)
plt.xticks(list(np.arange(1, 72, 9)))
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]